# segue parse data from a tableviewcontroller to another

Tags: swift, uitableview, parse-platform, uisearchbar

I have a tableview with a search bar. The search bar returns PFUsers whose usernames contain the text in the search bar. That part works fine and the users fetched are displayed in the tableview. When the user tap on a tableview cell, I want to segue to another view controller which contains a table of images that the user tapped has posted. I set up the segue and below are my codes:

```
//usersSearched contains all the PFUsers whose usernames match the text in search bar 
       var usersSearched = [PFObject]()

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

// showImages is the segue triggered when cell is tapped
    if segue.identifier == "showImages" {

        let pointInTable: CGPoint = sender!.convertPoint(sender!.bounds.origin, toView: searchResultTable)
        let cellIndexPath = searchResultTable.indexPathForRowAtPoint(pointInTable)

        let showImages = segue.destinationViewController as! ShowImagesViewController

        let userSelected = usersSearched[cellIndexPath!.row]

        let getImagesQuery = PFQuery(className: "allImages")

        getImagesQuery.whereKey("userId", equalTo: userSelected["userId"]!)

        getImagesQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (posts, error) -> Void in

            if let posts = posts {

                showImages.pictureFile.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)

                for post in posts {

                    if let file = post["imageFile"] as? PFFile {

                        showImages.pictureFile.append(file)

                    } else {

                        let replacementImageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(UIImage(named: "whiteBackground.jpg")!, 0.8)

                        let replacementImageFile = PFFile(name: "replacementImageFile.jpeg", data: replacementImageData!)

                        showImages.pictureFile.append(replacementImageFile)
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
```

The above codes are from the view controller containing the search bar and tableview

Below are my codes for the view controller which display the images:

```
    var pictureFile = [PFFile]()

    @IBOutlet var imageTableView: UITableView!


func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

    return 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return pictureFile.count
}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("imageCell") as! imageTableViewCell

        pictureFile[indexPath.row].getDataInBackgroundWithBlock { (fileData, error) -> Void in

            if let downloadedImage = UIImage(data: fileData!) {

                cell.imageHere.image = downloadedImage
            }
        }

        return cell
    }
```

So my problem is that the images appear do not belong to the PFUser tapped. And an unwind segue is provided automatically on the view controller that displays the images with a typical back button on nav bar. When I clicked on it, it does segue back to the search controller, however, when I type in the search bar to search again, it either returns nothing or a PFUser that do not contain the search bar text. I tried my best explaining everything, I know it sound too confusing, but please help! thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you know how to put the images into a tableViewController. If not, check out how to make a tableViewCellClass.

You're going to want to use didSelectRowAtIndexPath (this will detect which cell the user tapped on). In the tableView that fetches users, you do not need to pull any image data...this will happen when you populate the image tableVC.

```
 // Delete any text within < > and replace with your own code

var selectedCellText = ""


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {


        // This gets the textLabel (in your case, the username) of the selected cell
        let cellIndexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!
        let selectedCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(cellIndexPath)! as UITableViewCell




    // Here you can add any details before you go to the next viewController, such as sending over the username of the selected user to the next viewController

    // This sets the variable above to the username, you will use it in prepare for segue
    selectedCellText = selectedCell.textLabel!.text!

    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("< identifier >", sender: self)



}


override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {



        let destinationVC : < viewController that you want to go to > = segue.destinationViewController as! < viewController that you want to go to >

        // destVC.username refers to a variable that has to be created in the next view controller. Once you present the next VC, you can check to make sure that "username" = < a username available in the database > and load that user's images
        destinationVC.username = selectedCellText



}
```

At this point, when the user taps on a tableView Cell, the next table will appear and you can load the images into the cells of that tableView